# Add Custom Layer in Google maps v2 in Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to create a custom Layer(Like traffic , etc in google maps v2) in Google maps, which will show some geo points that I will given to mapview. Is there any possibility of implementing this in google maps with the new API ?? If so please provide some methods and code samples.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the official tutorial:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker

or have a look at (Explanation for the changes between API v1 --> v2):

[How to add overlay in google maps API v2 | Android |](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14114131/how-to-add-overlay-in-google-maps-api-v2-android)

[Android Maps-API v2: where are the Overlays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14526482/android-maps-api-v2-where-are-the-overlays)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `GroundOverlayOptions` object to set an image on the map. Together with `.positionFromBounds(bounds)` you should be able to cover your specific area.

Have a look at 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/groundoverlay

Code sample:

```
LatLng NEWARK = new LatLng(40.714086, -74.228697);

GroundOverlayOptions newarkMap = new GroundOverlayOptions()
            .image(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.newark_nj_1922))
        .position(NEWARK, 8600f, 6500f);
map.addGroundOverlay(newarkMap);
```

Also you can consider `Shapes` https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/shapes

```
// Instantiates a new Polygon object and adds points to define a rectangle
PolygonOptions rectOptions = new PolygonOptions()
          .add(new LatLng(37.35, -122.0),
               new LatLng(37.45, -122.0),
               new LatLng(37.45, -122.2),
               new LatLng(37.35, -122.2),
               new LatLng(37.35, -122.0));

// Get back the mutable Polygon
Polygon polygon = myMap.addPolygon(rectOptions);
```